# window.location.href - Left hand side of operator '=' must be a reference.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting this error:

```
Left hand side of operator '=' must be a reference.
```

when this script is run from a select menu change:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#productType').change(function() {
    window.location.href = window.location.href + '&productType=' = $(this).val();
  });
});
```

It's highlighting this line:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + '&productType=' = $(this).val();
```

as being the problem. Anyone know what's wrong with that line? I'm simply trying to add some parameters to the current URL and then perform the GET request again in the current page.

Comment: For concatenation, use `+` operator. While typing `+` you didn't press SHIFT key. Complete code: `window.location.href += '&productType=' + $(this).val()`

Comment: You want `+` instead of that second `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used one extra `=` operator in this line

```
 window.location.href = window.location.href + '&productType=' = $(this).val();
 --------------------------------------------------------------^
```

replace this extra `=` with `+` operator to concatenate the value

```
 window.location.href = window.location.href + '&productType=' + $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 4):

You have

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + '&productType=' = $(this).val();
```

when it should be

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + '&productType=' + $(this).val();
```

notice the extra '=' sign instead of +

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using an `=` sign instead of a `+` sign:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + '&productType=' = $(this).val();
--------------------------------------------------------------^
```